# How to print string value from breakpoint action in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb, debugging

I have a breakpoint action and am using the Log option from the drop down.  I'd like to print out the string (summary) value.  I'm doing this:

```
the person name is: @p.name@
```

but that prints the memory address.  I can switch to the Debugger Command option and do

```
po f.name
```

but then I lose my description, as used in the first option.  Using the Log option, is there a way to print the string value and not the memory address?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. Add a Log function from the drop-down, then add another box and select `Debugger Command` and enter `po f.name`.

If you want your log to be more complicated, you could do something more like this:

```
the person name is: @(const char *)[(NSString*)[p.name description] UTF8String]@
```

You best bet is probably to just use the debugger's graphical interface to watch variables. If you want to log messages, use `NSLog`.

Comment: In my case, XCode simply ignores whatever I type. Does the type of debugger matter (ie GDB / LLDB)?

Comment: @futureelite7 The both GDB and LLDB should be able to do this. You could try using the "Expression" action instead of "Log Message" then just `NSLog` there. So, in the "Expression" window you'd type something like: `(void)NSLog(@"Log this variable: %@", aVariable);`

Comment: @JasonCoco it seems the Expression action is not there in Xcode 4.6.

Comment: Sometimes such tweak helps:
`the person name is: @(const char *)[(NSString*)[[(id)p name] description] UTF8String]@`

Comment: If you're doing this with multiple breakpoints that are similar, I suggest adding a prefix to your message to make it easy to filter the output in the console log.

Set the action to **Log Message**.
Set the content of the message to `#### event name: @eventName@`.
And use **####* as the search pattern in the console log pane.

Answer (score 28):

You can use NSLog statements with breakpoints using "Debugger Command", but you need to add "expr"

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"The Person Name is %@", p.name)
```

-

[image: using expr command with a Debugger Command as breakpoint in Xcode 4.4]

Comment: This had me confused for a bit, in your expression you're using “ instead of " for quotes. They look nearly identical in Xcode. For anyone else, while it was in there it was giving this error `error: unexpected '@' in program`.

Comment: Thanks Mike; I did not notice this. It must have been automatically replaced while I copy/pasted the expression. Fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution using only one action, and using fewer characters than the `expr` solution.

[image: debugger command using NSlog]

However, unless you add the `void` like this:

```
po (void)NSLog(@"the person name is: %@", p.name)
```

you will get an annoying "nil" printed out with your log. for example:

```
(lldb) po NSLog(@"foo")
 nil
2013-06-19 14:42:59.025 TheMove[95864:c07] foo

(lldb) po (void)NSLog(@"foo")
2013-06-19 14:43:10.758 TheMove[95864:c07] foo
```

If you can live with the nil (I can) it's faster to type and easier to remember just the `po`

Comment: I've tried to use the @expr@ syntax many times with very little success. This is a really simple workaround, thanks!

Comment: FYI: When using Swift, this would look like `po NSLog("the person name is: %@", p.name)`

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using 2 different actions for the same breakpoint. First a Log and then a debugger command with po varName. Only downside it will print in 2 different rows.

[image]

Comment: You can use one action like Jason suggests

Answer (score 1):

For Swift and Xcode 12.2 you can double click on the breakpoint and use `Debugger Command` as an action and as a command whatever you usually time on the debugger.

In the example I use `po` with a string as param (to avoid printing the memory address) which contains the values I am debugging. I also enable `Automatically continue...` to avoid stopping the execution.

[image]

You can also add other text or other variables.

A thing to keep in mind though, running these takes some time, so for operations where timing is important, these are not good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need **TWO actions** in the breakpoint, you can just have **ONE** command (log message), where you put the message including the content of variables (see image). By clicking "automatically continues" it is just acting like having a print-command in code, but the good thing is, then you dont have print statements in your code.

[image]

Comment: That does not work currently with strings. I really wish that it did :(