# expr (void)NSLog(@"someString is %@", someString)

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, lldb

I've got this as a Debugger Action in a breakpoint:

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"someString is %@", someString)
```

but it's barfing with:

```
error: warning: expression result unused
error: cannot find interface declaration for '$__lldb_objc_class'
error: cannot find interface declaration for '$__lldb_objc_class'
error: 2 errors parsing expression
```

Why's it not working?

====
UPDATE

I tried this in a completely new Xcode project. And it works fine. So, to be clear, this line has no syntactical problems in Xcode 4.6:

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"someString is %@", someString)
```

However, copying the exact same line from the breakpoint to my previous Xcode project results in the same problem.

Could it be something I've changed in the Build Settings for this specific project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are not reaching this code from within a block. This would explain why the same breakpoint works in a new project but not in the other. This is what happens when trying to print the value of objects while at breakpoints within blocks. The solution is to use an NSLog in the block to do the printouts rather than using breakpoints. It's annoying, I know.

Comment: Thanks - yes, it was being executed in a block. Wonder why. After all, someString was local to the block. Got a link? I can't seem to find any info on this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you copied that incorrectly, I would say the double-quote characters are invalid.  How about:

```
expr (void)NSLog(@"someString is %@", someString)
```

If you did copy it correctly, then it's a [known bug](https://devforums.apple.com/message/758329#758329).

Comment: He copied it incorrectly from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742456/how-to-print-string-value-from-breakpoint-action-in-xcode-4) as it seems... +1 for spotting it though

Comment: Nope - first thing I checked were the speech marks. Never copy and paste speech marks! Fwiw, I'm using Xcode 4.6. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @SnowCrash Not that I know of; however I know I have had that working just fine in Xcode 4.5 and 4.6, so I believe that should work without issue.  However if you copied the quotes correctly, why are they incorrect in your question?

Comment: Copied here from a Word doc. I guess I should say "Never copy and paste quotes into code OR StackOverflow"! But just to check, I erased and retyped quotes into my breakpoint - same result. Fixed question.

Comment: Tested with a new project - see my Update. So, the problem is not quotes and not a bug.

Comment: @SnowCrash OK, I cannot explain why it would fail on one project however.  Unless gdb is used as the debugger of course...

Comment: @trojanfoe Build Options > Compiler > LLVM 4.2. OK, no problem - thanks for having a think about it.

Comment: @SnowCrash That's the compiler, not the debugger.  However I would have thought that it's probably already lldb.

Comment: @trojanfoe If I do Edit Schemes > Run > Info I see LLDB under Debugger. I assume this means I'm using lldb.

Comment: @SnowCrash Yeah looks like.  I cannot explain the issue.